# Retrive Informations about currently running sessions using Windows.Media.Control with C++/WinRT

Tags: c++, uwp, visual-studio-2019, c++-winrt

I would like to know, how to retrive informations(e.g application name) about all the sessions that are currently running.

```
GlobalSystemMediaTransportControlsSessionManager SessionManager();
IVectorView<GlobalSystemMediaTransportControlsSession> Sessions;
Sessions = SessionManager.GetSessions();
// for sessions - session.SourceAppUserModelId
```

I want to learn WinRT with C++, so I ve been trying to do something with Windows Media Control, but looking at the documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.control?view=winrt-22621,
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.control.globalsystemmediatransportcontrolssessionmanager?view=winrt-22621
I have no idea what I should do. I would appreciate any links to tutorials or explanations on how to do it or learn it.

Comment: There's no answerable question here, at all. Please take the [tour] and see [ask]. If you need an intro into C++/WinRT, see [this link](https://aka.ms/cppwinrt). Take note that C++/WinRT assumes that users are C++ experts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using, trial and error method, I have finally achived what I was looking for, in a way.
Hopefully, it will be usefull to someone other, than me. 
I didn't know, you have to pass NULL as parameter to GlobalSystemMediaTransportControlsSessionManager class, for some reason. 
Also, had some problem with converting hstring to string, but I found a function winrt::to_string().

```
    GlobalSystemMediaTransportControlsSessionManager SessionManager(NULL);
    // get SessionManager to provide access to info of playback
    if (SessionManager == NULL) {
        // gets SessionManager instance
        IAsyncOperation session_async = SessionManager.RequestAsync();
        // waits 5 seconds before failure
        if (session_async.wait_for(std::chrono::seconds{ 5 }) == AsyncStatus::Completed) {
            SessionManager = session_async.GetResults();
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "Couldnt request instance of Session Manager" << std::endl;
        }
        std::cout << "Done" << std::endl;
    }
    
    IVectorView<GlobalSystemMediaTransportControlsSession> sessions = SessionManager.GetSessions();
    
    int i = 0;
    for (auto const &session : sessions) {
        std::cout << i << ' ';
        // get Application name
        winrt::hstring session_name = session.SourceAppUserModelId();
        std::cout << " name- " << winrt::to_string(session_name);

        // pause session
        IAsyncOperation<bool> paused = session.TryPauseAsync();
        i++;
    }
```

Comment: Oh, thanks I thought I did it already.